# How to create driver for both OS (Android and IOS) on one script

Tags: android, ios, automation, appium, cross-platform

first time I need to set up a React-native app automation.
The app developed for two OS's, android and IOS.

The question is how to get the current OS that running now on device, and set a relevant driver.

For example: I connected a device with an IOS operating system, clicked the "Run All Tests" button, and the relevant driver came into operation.

I have set up two AppiumDriver type drivers, with one returning a Android operating system driver and the other an IOS.

AppiumDriver driver;
    URL appiumUrl = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");

```
public DriverSettings() throws MalformedURLException {
}


public AppiumDriver getAndroidDriver() {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "**TBD**");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "**TBD**");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appUrl);
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.NO_SIGN, true);
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.UNICODE_KEYBOARD, true); //set unicodekeyboard in order to support umlauts
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.RESET_KEYBOARD, true); //reset keyboard after tests
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.IGNORE_UNIMPORTANT_VIEWS, true); //speeds up tests, as views that are not important i.e. for accessiblity are not shown on android. Is disabled on demand in tests using driver.ignoreunimporantViews
    return driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumUrl, cap);
}

public AppiumDriver getIOSDriver() {

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.3");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appUrl);

    return driver = new IOSDriver(appiumUrl, cap);
}
```

So how to check ones before i running all tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can make one common driver method which on the basis of the platform(iOS or android) will return the desired driver.

You can do it like:

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver(String platformName) {
if (platformName.equals("Android")) {
    // setup the android driver
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "**TBD**");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "**TBD**");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appUrl);
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.NO_SIGN, true);
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.UNICODE_KEYBOARD, true); //set unicodekeyboard in order to support umlauts
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.RESET_KEYBOARD, true); //reset keyboard after tests
    cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.IGNORE_UNIMPORTANT_VIEWS, true); //speeds up tests, as views that are not important i.e. for accessiblity are not shown on android. Is disabled on demand in tests using driver.ignoreunimporantViews
    driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumUrl, cap);
} else if (platformName.equals("iOS")) {
    // setup the ios driver
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.3");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appUrl);
    driver = new IOSDriver(appiumUrl, cap);
}
return driver;
}
```

Comment: Yes , its looks good, but the question is how to check platform name ?
I tried System.getenv("PLATFORM"); but receive null all the time

Comment: @Michael  I don't think there is any command which would specifically tell which platform is connected to the pc. Though `xcrun instruments -s devices` is used to get the iOS devices connected to the system and `adb devices` to get the android devices connected. So you can run these commands and get the devices and according set the driver.